# Распознавание изображений

Tags: c#, opencv

Хочу реализовать распознавание изображений на экране.

Коллекция картинок статична, т.е. неизменно кол-во и вид картинок (никаких искажений и прочее). Блоку, который будет распознавать изображения, известны все возможные варианты.
Я предполагаю, распознавание будет производится на основе сравнения текущей картинки(-ок) со всеми возможными. С чего можно начать работу над задачей?

Не очень глубокое гугление дало библиотеку OpenCV.

Comment: Ну и начните с OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Вам нужна нейросеть.

Я пробовал библиотеку `AForge`, а еще посмотрите видео на канале [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfelJa0QlJWwPEZ6XNbNRyA). Там, вобщем-то и используется эта библиотека. Плюс к этому очень хорошая теоретическая база. Ищите видео с названиями AIML-4-...

Comment: Зачем нужна нейросеть, если все варианты известны и искажений нет?

Comment: спасибо за ссылку на канал. @Qwertiy а вы как бы решали эту задачу?

Comment: @cruim, собственно, так как ты описал в вопросе - сравнением с образцами.